# Read all active directory users for a particular CN and OU

Tags: active-directory, directory, ldap

I have a requirment to read all active directory users for a specified OU and CN, can you please provide the exact syntax for 
LDAP PATH:
QUERY:
Properties:

Please find details below for my AD:

```
LDAP PATH: LDAP://SERVER1.AI.US.AII.LOCAL:389/DC=AI,DC=us,DC=AII,DC=local
```

Other values
`OU=Security Groups`
`CN=AB_E-P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search requests must contain at a minimum the following parameters:

- the base object at which the search starts (no objects above the base objects are returned)
- the scope of the search: `base` is the base object itself, `one` is the base object and
  one level below the base object, `sub` is the base object and all entries below the base object.
- a filter which limits the entries returned to those entries which match the assertion in the
  filter

A list of attributes can also be supplied, though many, but not all, LDAP APIs will request all 
user attributes if none are supplied in the search request.

Use `DC=AI,DC=us,DC=AII,DC=local` as the base object, and the appropriate filter that will result in the server returning matching entries in the search response, one possible filter would be `(cn=ab_e-p)`.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: Hi Terry, I am facing issue with no of record,please find below my C# code to read ad, i am geting less no of record in comperision of any third party or microsoft tool.

Comment: '            DirectoryEntry de = GetDirectoryEntry();
            DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
            List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
            deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
            deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(memberOf=CN=UG_I_SP-BA,OU=Security Groups,DC=i,DC=us,DC=p,DC=local))";
deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
SearchResult result = deSearch.FindOne();
SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
message.show(results.count);'

Comment: The `(objectClass=*)` portion of the filter should be removed. `(objectClass=*)` is a `present` filter, and all entries contain at least one `objectClass`. Your filter will cause the search response to return all entries that are members of that group (subject to access rights of the authentication ID of the connection).

Comment: Unfortunately, the above links no longer work, and Mr. Gardner has apparently passed away.